# When does the pdf exist, given a cdf?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For a random variable $X$ with cdf

$F(x) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{3x+1}{3x+2} & \text{if } x \geq 0 \newline
0 & \text{if } x < 0
\end{cases}$

How do I check whether $X$ has a density?

So far I know that there is a jump at $x = 0$ from $\lim_{x\uparrow 0}F(x) = 0$ to $F(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ but this alone is as far as I know not enough to rule out that the pdf exists.

So what do I have to check in general and in this instance, to see that the pdf does indeed (not) exist?

I checked other questions but either the answer I was looking for was not provided or there was no answer at all.

Comment: "...but this alone is as far as I know not enough to rule out that the pdf exists" Actually, this is **enough** to assert the non-existence of a density. Continuity of CDF is a necessary condition for a PDF to exist. (In fact, existence of a PDF is equivalent to what is called *absolute continuity*, which is basically a stronger notion than mere continuity.)

Comment: Having a jump in the CDF is enough to say the distribution cannot be fully described with a density, as there is point of positive probability at the jump.  But it is a one-way implication: there are also distributions with a continuous CDF which do not have a density, such as the Cantor distribution.

Comment: @SangchulLee So if there is even only a single point at which the CDF is not continuous anywhere on the domain, then the PDF does not exist?

Comment: That is correct :)

Comment: @SangchulLee Great, thanks for the confirmation. I am, however, assuming that this is not the only way that one can see that the PDF does not exist. I tried to read through the wiki page of absolute continuity as Trevor suggested in his answer below, but I couldn't quite work out the most important bit. So if there are other conditions, what are they?

Comment: Typically, you don't need to worry about checking absolute continuity for two reasons: **(1)** If mere continuity fails for the CDF, then absolute continuity (and hence existence of PDF) also fails for that CDF. **(2)** It's a rare occurrence to come across a distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ whose CDF is continuous but not absolutely continuous. Such $\mu$ is called *singular*, and this hints that $\mu$ is supported on a subset of fractional dimension, i.e., a fractal. Such examples are rarely encountered in practice, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @AtK42 their* answer

Comment: See here for examples of singular functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_function

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

A function $f(x)$ is a PDF for $X$ if $\mathbf{P}(X \in A) = \int_A f$ for every measurable set (or sufficiently, for every interval) $A$.

In particular, if $A$ is a singleton set like $A = \{0\}$ then $$ \mathbf{P}(X \in A) = \mathbf{P}(X = 0) = \int_{\{0\}} f = 0. $$

But in terms of the CDF for this problem,

$$ \mathbf{P}(X = 0) = F(0) - F(0^-) = \frac12. $$

(Here $F(a^-)$ means $\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} F(x)$.)

The term for distributions having a PDF is [absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) which you can look at for more information.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very well versed in measure theory. How exactly does this show for this problem that the PDF does not exist?

Comment: @AtK42 For this distribution, $\mathbf{P}(X = 0) = \frac12$ but if there was a PDF, then $\mathbf{P}(X = 0) = \int_{\{0\}} f = 0$. So there cannot be a PDF.

Comment: How is the integral $\int_{\{0\}} f$ defined?

Comment: @AtK42 To integrate over $[a, b]$, you partition the interval and take a limit of Riemann sums. But if $a$ and $b$ are both $0$ then your Riemann sums are always $0$ since $\Delta x = 0$.

Comment: So the argument is that the interval is a single point, i.e. lower limit = upper limit, hence as for any continuous distribution, the probability of the random variable attaining a single value is $0$? I guess I am a bit confused by the $f$ in $\int_{\{0\}} f$ since I assume this stands for the PDF which in this case does not even exist.

Answer (score 0):

In the book entitled "*Introduction to Random Signal Analysis and Kalman Filtering*" (John Willey & Sons, 1983), the author Robert G. Brown showed an example, where a real-valued noise, whose value has a pdf symmetric about $0$, is applied to an ideal diode that passes positive input values perfectly but blocks negative input values completely. Then the output noise (denoted as $x$) will have a pdf which is same as the input noise' pdf for $x > 0$, and zero for $x < 0$, while the pdf at $x = 0$ is a Dirac delta (impulse) of magnitude $1/2$. That is, for the CDF given by the OP, the pdf of $X$ is

$f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{3}{(3x+2)^2} & \text{if } x \gt 0 \newline
0 & \text{if } x < 0 \newline \frac{1}{2}\delta(x) & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}$